# How to upgrade percona mysql on debian squeeze

Tags: mysql, debian, percona

Was running an apt upgrade and

```
The following packages have been kept back:
libmysqlclient18 percona-server-client-5.5 percona-server-server-5.5
```

I'm currently running percona mysql 5.5.15-55-log

Trying `sudo apt-get install percona-server-server-5.5` I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
percona-server-server-5.5 : Depends: percona-server-client-5.5 (>= 5.5.17-rel22.1-197.squeeze) but 5.5.15-rel21.0-160.squeeze is to be installed
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

More for Z:

```
# apt-cache policy percona-server-client-5.5
percona-server-client-5.5:
  Installed: 5.5.15-rel21.0-160.squeeze
  Candidate: 5.5.17-rel22.1-197.squeeze
  Version table:
     5.5.17-rel22.1-197.squeeze 0
        500 http://repo.percona.com/apt/ squeeze/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.5.15-rel21.0-160.squeeze 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

When I run `apt-get install percona-server-server percona-server-client`

```
Get:1 http://repo.percona.com/apt/ squeeze/main percona-server-client all 5.5.17-rel22.1-197.squeeze [2624 B]
Get:2 http://repo.percona.com/apt/ squeeze/main percona-server-server all 5.5.17-rel22.1-197.squeeze [2736 B]
```

Then if I `apt-get upgrade` it shows:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  libmysqlclient18 percona-server-client-5.5 percona-server-server-5.5
```

Trying `apt-get install libmysqlclient18 percona-server-client-5.5 percona-server-server-5.5` I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient18 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5.18-1~dotdeb.1)
```

Sure, adding /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
# deb http://94.75.223.121/debian squeeze main

deb http://94.75.223.121/debian squeeze main non-free contrib
deb-src http://94.75.223.121/debian squeeze main non-free contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free

# squeeze-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://94.75.223.121/debian squeeze-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://94.75.223.121/debian squeeze-updates main contrib non-free

# dotdeb
# deb http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all
# deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all
deb http://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/dotdeb/ stable all
deb-src http://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/dotdeb/ stable all

# percona
deb http://repo.percona.com/apt squeeze main
deb-src http://repo.percona.com/apt squeeze main
```

No pinnings that I've added yet.

Comment: Re-run apt-get update maybe?  The newest version appears to be in the repository (http://repo.percona.com/apt/).  What do you get when you run `apt-cache policy percona-server-client-5.5`?

Comment: Usually you should just update your question with the details.  What happens when you run `apt-get install percona-server-server percona-server-client` or `apt-get install libmysqlclient18 percona-server-client-5.5 percona-server-server-5.5`?

Comment: updated the original post/question

Comment: Post your full sources.list and any current apt pinning settings, if you need further help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
libmysqlclient18 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5.18-1~dotdeb.1)
```

This error here seems to strongly indicate what your problem is.

You appear to mixing and matching several different repositories.  It appears you have at least the official, percona, and dotdeb repositories.  Somehow you have gotten into a state where it seems like the dotdeb libmysqlclient18 version has been choose as the installation candidate, but this appears to require a package that isn't available or installable for some reason.

You may have to do some apt pinning to make sure the packages are chosen from the correct repository.  In this case libmysqlclient18 probably needs to come from the percona repo.

Comment: added output of sources.list above

Comment: in /etc/apt/preferences.d/percona (new) I set the priority of the percona repo higher (700) and reran apt update, upgrade, that worked.  Thanks for the lead.